# print white square box in downloaded csv from interactive report

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2

I have Using `chr(27)` in My Query to print white square box in the Interactive report However Its Printing exactly when i runt the report its shows the exact  , When I download the reports from IR action menu as csv file its doesn't shows exactly like  but it shows like

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NZ-cR9t3ZVKeJIiKdkpv0qYfr8yFyAzT/view?usp=sharing

Please share the suggestion how to print it like complete square not 50%

Answer (score 0):

The way a character is displayed in a csv depends on the application opening the csv file.
I suggest working the other way around: find the character that does what you want when the csv is opened by the application you use, and then replace chr(27) with it